# Alter a table column based on type

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I am converting "timestamps without timezone" columns to "timestamps with timezone" on a number of tables. These are large tables and I am going to use batching and other approaches to reduce the time the tables are exclusively locked while data is converted.

Once this procedure is complete, I want to follow up with an application deploy, that uses migration scripts to keep the schema in sync.

When these scripts run I want to check if a column type is already "timezone with timestamp before altering it"?

How can I conditionally carry out the alteration based on a column type check and skip it if it is already a certain type?

Comment: Why worry? Behind the scenes, PostgreSQL may very well do nothing if the column's data type is already what you're trying to set it to? Why don't you try with a (reasonably sized) sample?

Comment: To be honest, I never thought of this. I'll try it out.

Comment: Thinking about this - you could ask on one of the PostgreSQL mailing lists - questions about server source code are not usual dba questions - having said that, there are people who actually contribute to the system who hang out here and there are those who know their way around the source code.

Comment: I just checked it out against a couple of tables. 1 with 15 million rows and one with 40 million rows and they both took under 100 ms when I attempted to use alter to change an already converted row, so they must be just skipping the operation.

Comment: Do you try with a changed row? TIMESTAMPTZ -> TIMESTAMP (or vice versa - try both...)! Write it up an answer with numbers and I'll upvote it! `\timing`... :-)

Answer (score 1):

To recreate Vérace suggestion and show they they are correct:

> create table if not exists check_change_type
> (
> column_to_change_to_tz timestamp without time zone
> )
> [2021-07-02 14:43:57] completed in 100 ms

> insert into check_change_type
> select
> clock_timestamp()
> from generate_series(1, 40000000)

[2021-07-02 14:48:13] 40,000,000 rows affected in 4 m 5 s 925 ms

> ALTER TABLE check_change_type ALTER column_to_change_to_tz TYPE timestamptz USING column_to_change_to_tz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'

[2021-07-02 14:53:29] completed in 3 m 52 s 416 ms

> ALTER TABLE check_change_type ALTER column_to_change_to_tz TYPE timestamptz

[2021-07-02 14:54:09] completed in 97 ms